# A table contains forbidden words which you cannot use in a comment - is it a value object in DDD?

Tags: domain-driven-design, value-object

My aggregate root is "Post" and sub aggregate is "Comment". In my database I have a table called "ForbiddenWords" with one column "Name" (it contains words for example: "sex", "porn"). If someone wants to add a comment, he can't use forbidden words. I need to create a class "ForbiddenWords" to validate a comment. Is this class a Value Object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A value object is an object without identity. According to your description, a forbidden word is a value object.

For example, you would not be able to distinguish in your table two rows with the same word. Moreover if you would change a word, it would be different word with no relation to the previous one (the identity would not persist after across the changes).

Comment: OK, thank you, so you resolved my doubts. :) One more question - do you think I can check if a comment doesn't contain forbidden words in a command handler CreateCommentCommandHandler, or it has to be in the domain model Comment?

Comment: Command handlers should not contain business logic. Checking comments for forbidden words is business logic.

Comment: Where to put validation logic is a broad topic. There are a couple of questions here (for example https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/210799/209774 or https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/341564/209774 ). If you don’t find a suitable answer, I’d suggest that you raise a separate question (and explain what makes you hesitate about not having it in the domain model).

Comment: thank you Christophe :)